# aggregating by one column while keeping the ID from another column

Tags: r, aggregate, plyr

I am still fairly new to R and have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
    > head(df)
           UniqueID                   Disbursements  Year
    1 NL-KVK-41160054-100530              303742     2010
    2 NL-KVK-41160054-100530              289829     2010
    3 NL-KVK-41160054-100530              577072     2010
    4 NL-KVK-41160054-100530              340292     2010
    5 NL-KVK-41160054-100530              555826     2011
    6 NL-KVK-41160054-100530              713332     2011
    > tail(df)
            UniqueID                    Disbursements      Year
    3041 NL-KVK-41160054-317/10481              200000     2009
    3042 NL-KVK-41160054-317/10481              284500     2010
    3043 NL-KVK-41160054-317/10481              737659     2010
    3044 NL-KVK-41160054-317/10481              405664     2011
    3045 NL-KVK-41160054-317/10481               10572     2012
    3046 NL-KVK-41160054-317/10481              114035     2013
```

I am trying to sum all the disbursements by year, but within each UniqueID, repeating the UniqueId where there are multiple years. So that my resulting dataframe will look like this:

```
         UniqueID                    Disbursements    Year
     NL-KVK-41160054-100530              1510935     2010
     NL-KVK-41160054-100530              769158      2011
     ...
            UniqueID                 Disbursements     Year
     NL-KVK-41160054-317/10481              200000     2009
     NL-KVK-41160054-317/10481              1022159    2010
     NL-KVK-41160054-317/10481              405664     2011
     NL-KVK-41160054-317/10481               10572     2012
     NL-KVK-41160054-317/10481              114035     2013
```

Based on how I pulled this data and got it into this dataframe, there should not be any NAs to contend with.

I've tried using aggregate:
`amt_by_year <- aggregate(Disbursements~UniqueID+Year, df, FUN=sum)`
but that throws an error of `Error in model.frame.default(formula = Disbursements ~ UniqueID + Year,  : variable lengths differ (found for 'Year')` I'm guessing because it's assuming there would be the same number of unique values in UniqueId and Year.

I've also tried ddply `amt_by_year <-ddply(NEWerDF,.(DateYear,UniqueID),summarise, Disbursements = sum(as.numeric(Disbursements)))` and got more errors, of NAs introduced by coercion.

I feel like there's something basic that I'm missing, because surely this is not this first time someone's had this problem. But I scoured stackoverflow and only found instances where the asker wanted to total the equivalent of both the ID and the Disbursement or only had two columns or something, so apologies if this has been asked before.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: with dplyr `df %>% group_by(UniqueID, Year) %>% summarise(sum(Disbursements))`. In base R: `aggregate(Disbursements~., df, sum)`

Comment: Using `aggregate(Disbursements~UniqueID+Year, df, sum)` on the given data gives me a normal output without errors

Comment: If you are getting errors still, you may need to ignore NA values. `aggregate(Disbursements~., df, sum, na.rm=TRUE)`

Comment: Hi and thanks to you both, but the aggregate function in base is what I have been trying and it still doesn't work, even if I ignore NAs. I feel like I'm getting closer with dplyr, but I'm confused by the %>% 's in your explanation Pierre. (Sorry, I'm still very new at all of this.)

Comment: Scratch that. I was confused by the special operators, but now I've got it. The first answer in dplyr works great! Thanks!